# How to put a text label on a plot located independently from the data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to put a text label on a ggplot, but I do not want to give the coordinates of the label in the data coordinates, but use some kind of coordinates that are not related to the data.
I know the transformation trick:

```
xrng <- range(x)
yrng <- range(y)
plot <- plot + annotate("text",x = xrng[2], y = yrng[2], label="bla") # plot label on top right
```

But this does not work well for plots with a logarithmic scale (and you have to do the transformation, which may not always be as easy as in the example).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplot2` plots are made with `grid` graphics so you can use `grid` commands to annotate the plot.

```
library('ggplot2')
library('grid')
qplot(rnorm(10))
grid.text('my label')
```

`?grid.text` gives several ways of specifying the coordinates.  Maybe one of them will make sense in your case.

Comment: `?grid.text` shows me that it's possible to specify coordinates using the `unit(x,"npc")` which is exactly what I need, but I can't get it to work. Actually, your own example does not work for me as well. I get the plot but no text.

Comment: You should see the label smack dead center of the plot.  Perhaps restart `R` and/or reinstall/updated `ggplot2`.  See if examples from `ggplot2` and 'grid` behave normally, like the one in `?grid.text`  Somethings not right, clearly.

Comment: Yes, it works. Turns out that my problem is related to something else, that I will ask in a separate question.